# Cannot save variables in Gatling session when validated with 'checkIf'

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have an API with 2 possible responses.

I have the below HTTP builder:

```
http("HelloTest")
.post(host + "/hello")
.headers(someHeader)
.body(StringBody(requestPayload))
.check(status.saveAs("responseStatus"))

.check(checkIf((response: Response, session: Session) => session("responseStatus").as[String] == "202")(jsonPath("$.error") is "Waiting for Response"))

.check(checkIf((response: Response, session: Session) => session("responseStatus").as[String] == "200")(jsonPath("$.foo").saveAs("fooVar")))
.check(checkIf((response: Response, session: Session) => session("responseStatus").as[String] == "200")(jsonPath("$").saveAs("responseBodyVar")))`
```

When I try to access the session variables `${fooVar}` and `${responseBodyVar}`, I see an error stating they are not defined.

How can I extract the session variables in the next `exec`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong in the request.

The code should look like this:

```
http("HelloTest")
.post(host + "/hello")
.headers(someHeader)
.body(StringBody(requestPayload))
.check(checkIf((response: Response, session: Session) => response.status.get.getStatusCode == "202")(jsonPath("$.error") is "Waiting for Response"))
.check(checkIf((response: Response, session: Session) => response.status.get.getStatusCode == "200")(jsonPath("$.foo").saveAs("fooVar")))
.check(checkIf((response: Response, session: Session) => response.status.get.getStatusCode == "200")(jsonPath("$").saveAs("responseBodyVar")))`
```

Comment: +1, worked for me, although I had to remove the double quotes from the status code to avoid a warning, I.E. `"202"` becomes `202`